# 'Create new view for output' in jupyter-lab does not work for holoviews

Tags: jupyter-lab, holoviews

I'm trying in jupyter-lab to 'create a new view for output' for a cell that outputs a holoviews plot (bokeh renderer). It just creates a second plot in the same window.

Here's some sample code to reproduce the problem.

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
hv.extension('bokeh')
hv.Violin(np.random.randn(100))
```

Create new view:
[image: create new view]

I get a copy in the original window:
[image: I get a copy in the original window]

Comment: I am facing same issue, where you able to find the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've given up.